# Shell: Adding newline after a alphanumeric character

Tags: shell, sed

I need to add a newline after the alphanumeric characters (example: 11.34s) in below paragraph - In Shell

Input:

```
zip_upload : Unzipping the new release at /path - 338.17s Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 4.78s zip_upload : Upload the zipped binaries to repository ---------- 2.48s zip_upload : Find the file applicatons.yml in remote node ------ 1.87s zip_upload : Upload to repository ---------------------- 0.92s zip_upload : include_tasks ------------------------------------------- 0.71s
```

Output needed as below:

```
zip_upload : Unzipping the new release at /path - 338.17s
Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 4.78s
zip_upload : Upload the zipped binaries to repository ---------- 2.48s
zip_upload : Find the file applicatons.yml in remote node ------ 1.87s
zip_upload : Upload to repository ---------------------- 0.92s
zip_upload : include_tasks ------------------------------------------- 0.71s
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
sed -r "s/([0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]s) /&\n/g" file
```

This sed looks for a patter `[digit].[digit][digit]s` and then replaces with the pattern matched(`&`) followed by a newline(`\n`).

Answer (score 1):

You have to redirect your output into

```
sed 's/[0-9]s/&\n/g'
```

Next command line simulates your output

```
echo "zip_upload : Unzipping the new release at /path - 338.17s Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 4.78s zip_upload : Upload the zipped binaries to repository ---------- 2.48s zip_upload : Find the file applicatons.yml in remote node ------ 1.87s zip_upload : Upload to repository ---------------------- 0.92s zip_upload : include_tasks ------------------------------------------- 0.71s"
```

If you redirect its output into the sed command with the arguments above, you will get the result you expect:

```
output=$(echo "zip_upload : Unzipping the new release at /path - 338.17s Gathering Facts --------------------------------------------------------- 4.78s zip_upload : Upload the zipped binaries to repository ---------- 2.48s zip_upload : Find the file applicatons.yml in remote node ------ 1.87s zip_upload : Upload to repository ---------------------- 0.92s zip_upload : include_tasks ------------------------------------------- 0.71s")
echo "$output" | sed 's/[0-9]s/&\n/g'
```